# XSLT Skips a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xslt that used to work previously, but now "skips" a node during transform and i don't understand why. what follows is a small portion of the xslt editi\ed down to be workable.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn" xmlns:com="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/common" xmlns:ent="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/enrollmententities" xmlns:pro="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/product" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pcext="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/Policy/V2.0/PolicyExtract">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="_PolicyPath" select="PolicyExtract/ContractLineOfCoverageList/ContractLineOfCoverage"/>
        <PolicyExtract>
            <xsl:copy-of select="pcext:TotalRecordCount"/>
            <ContractLineOfCoverageList>

            </ContractLineOfCoverageList>
        </PolicyExtract>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The node I want is  yet when i run the below text through it, it "skips" that node (and only that node) heres the xml that will fit through the provided xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PolicyExtract xmlns:ent="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/enrollmententities" xmlns:pcext="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/Policy/V2.0/PolicyExtract" xmlns:pro="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/product" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><pcext:TotalRecordCount>4</pcext:TotalRecordCount><ContractLineOfCoverageList></ContractLineOfCoverageList></PolicyExtract>
```

the TotalRecordCount is accounted for, but won't transfer over. I've tried it in a debugger as well, and it skips over that line.

any ideas?

Comment: Please post complete XML and XSLT, or better yet, the smallest complete set that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: the xslt that encompasses the problem is at the top, the xml that contains the node in question is below that

Comment: You need to post a small example input file. Without an input example, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change your `xsl:copy-of` statement from this**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="pcext:TotalRecordCount"/>
```

**to this**

```
<xsl:copy-of select="PolicyExtract/pcext:TotalRecordCount"/>
```

in order to copy over the `pcext:TotalRecordCount` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PolicyExtract xmlns:com="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/common"
               xmlns:ent="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/enrollmententities"
               xmlns:pro="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/V2.0/product"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:pcext="http://enrollmentservices.humana.com/Policy/V2.0/PolicyExtract">
   <pcext:TotalRecordCount>4</pcext:TotalRecordCount>
   <ContractLineOfCoverageList/>
</PolicyExtract>
```